# Trying to center fixed menu div on page

Tags: html, css, center

I've tried  a few different rules but I can get my top menu to center. When I change the position to absolute or relative it does go to the center but then the height goes to 100% for some reason. I don't have a set height because I want the five to be the size of the children.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="topWrapper">
    <a href="index.html">
        <header id="top_header">
            <h1>MacroPlay Games</h1>
        </header>
    </a>
    <nav id="topnav">
        <ul>
            <a href="index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
            <a href="about.html"><li>About</li></a>
            <a href="video.html"><li>Trailers</li></a>
        </ul>
    </nav>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#topWrapper {
    border:1px solid #00ffff;
    background-color:#0d0d0d;
    text-align:center;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:9999;
    width: 850px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    float:clear;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kjAAy/

Comment: It looks centered to me

Comment: it adjusts to the screen size. On a large enough screen it goes to the left.

Comment: But you have a fixed width of 850px on the header.  Perhaps that should be `min-width`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `margin:0 auto` with `left:0px; right:0px`

```
#topWrapper {
    border:1px solid #00ffff;
    background-color:#0d0d0d;
    text-align:center;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:9999;
    width: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto; left:0px; right:0px;
    float:clear;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kjAAy/1/)**

Same method works even for `position:absolute`

Comment: hmm that's an unexpected solution. It works however. Could you tell me why I needed to add right and left please?

Comment: left:0; right:0 removes the default alignment of the absolute div. So you can align the div with margin.

Comment: Oh I see. I never would have found that out. Thanks!

Comment: I keep being surprised at what I don't know about css. Thanks for a great tip

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a small error in the original code and also the code for the most popular response from Sowmya.

More specifically, the property in question is "float: clear;", and to my knowledge there's no such thing as "float: clear;"

Unfortunately, since I just created this account I'm unable to correct the error or reply to that post. Which is why I created a new post.

You can check out W3C for float CSS properties here:
http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/float

Values listed are "left | right | none | inherit"

Thanks for listening!

Answer (score 0):

```
Position="fixed" is not recommended though.
<div id="someid" align="center">
 --whatever code--
</div>
```

This would do. I recommend you should read the purpose of position tag.
   http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: "The <div> align attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead"

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use:

> ```
> border:1px solid #00ffff;
> background-color:#0d0d0d;
> text-align:center;
> position:fixed;
> z-index: 9999;
> width: 850px;
> float: clear;
> left: 50%; /* position halfway from the left of screen */    
> margin: 0px 0px -425px 0px; /* pull the div into center */ }
> ```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zXFdN/3/

ps align="center" is not supported in HTML5: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_div_align.asp